# Custom cell not showing in Table View-Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have made a custom cell and using its .xib to show in table view.
But the this cell is'nt showing in table view.While other custom cells are fine.

Cell Controller:

```
import UIKit

//Protocol to add action on button click
protocol ChatLinkButtonDelegate: class {
    func chatLinkClick(cell: ChatBankController)
}


class ChatBankController: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnseemore: CustomUIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year: CustomUILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var anwser: CustomUILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var month: CustomUILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var interest: CustomUILabel!

    var delegate: ChatLinkButtonDelegate?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.delegate = nil
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func btnChatLinkClick(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.chatLinkClick(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Table View controller to load and show data:
Registration:

```
cell = UINib(nibName: "ChatBank", bundle: nil)
            self.tbChat.register(cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatBankCell")
```

Loading cell to tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                    let cell:ChatBankController = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatBankCell") as! ChatBankController
                    cell.anwser.text="fine"
                    return cell

                    let cell = UITableViewCell()
                    return cell
    }
```

Comment: you have set tableview delegate or datasource

Comment: can you check if cell if dequeued correctly? add a debugPrint(cell) below the `let cell:ChatBankController = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell` line and post what prints

Comment: Thanks for reply,cell info:
<Ella.ChatBankController: 0x7f96288ef000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 2048 400); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000226520>>

Comment: No I have'nt set datasource and deleget in code

Comment: But it is added in story board and working fine with other customcells which have only 1 item like label/button.This custom cell which is getting problem have 4 labels and 1 button.

Comment: Empty cell :  let cell = UITableViewCell(). Why are you taking this?

Comment: In case of any of my cell's type not found,which is getting currently right now.

Comment: @KamranAhmed this is not effecting your code because above this you are using return. Once return will invoke the code below have no meaning. Secondly if you want to check type of cell you should do that with if- else.

Comment: Regarding issue, try to give background color to cell. To debug where is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register nib file in your view controller.swift file view did load method and set tableview datasource and delegate like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

yourTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName:"ProfileTableViewCell" , bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell")

yourTableView.datasource = self
yourTableView.delegate = self

    }
```

Comment: can you register Nib file ?

Comment: Doing the same as you have mentioned.

Comment: then not fault in coding fault in your constraint

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if you connected delegate and datsource of the table view in the storyboard.

Then try this code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatBankCell") as! ChatBankController
                cell.anwser.text="fine"
                return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes it is datasource,delegeted are connected because other custom cell is working fine which has only 1 label or 1 button.But this custom cell which is getting problem have some labels and a button.